# ¿Como evitar System.FormatException en conversiones que varian en el valor?

Tags: c#, arduino

Buenas tardes compañeros , estoy haciendo una interfaz que contiene progressbar que me muestran solamente el valor de uno sensores , sin embargo en el caso de que un sensor no este recibiendo ningun valor , como es el caso de que este en 0 me manda un error de tipo System.FormatException y quisiera saber si existe alguna condicion que me permita evitar esto si me lectura llegara a 0 pues lei en el manual de microsoft que esto siempre pasara cuando el valorse salga de los parametros o en mi caso llegue a 0 . agradeceria mucho su aporte

`  string input = TxtDatosRecibidos.Text;
            char[] delimitador = { ',' };

```
        string[] bufer = input.Split(delimitador);

        if (bufer.Length > 0)
            textBox1.Text = bufer[0];
            ss1.Value =Int32.Parse(bufer[0]); 



             if (bufer.Length >= 0)
             textBox2.Text = bufer[1];
             ss2.Value = Int32.Parse(bufer[1]);// aqui llega el error

            if (bufer.Length >=0)
               textBox3.Text = bufer[2];
              ss3.Value = Int32.Parse(bufer[2]);

            if (bufer.Length >= 0)
               textBox4.Text = bufer[3];
              ss4.Value = Int32.Parse(bufer[3]);

             if (bufer.Length >= 0)
                textBox5.Text = bufer[4];
            ss5.Value = Int32.Parse(bufer[4]);

             if (bufer.Length >= 0)
             textBox6.Text = bufer[5];
            ss6.Value = Int32.Parse(bufer[5]);

             if (bufer.Length >= 0)
                 textBox7.Text = bufer[6];
             ss7.Value = Int32.Parse(bufer[6]);

            if (bufer.Length >= 0)
                 textBox8.Text = bufer[7];
           ss8.Value = Int32.Parse(bufer[7]);
```

`

Answer (score 1):

Si quiere convertir a numerico pero sin que falle usa el `int.TryParse()`

```
int ss2 = 0;
int.TryParse(bufer[1], out ss2);

ss2.Value = ss2;
```

Tambien podrias valida si se realizo correctamente la conversion usando

```
int ss2 = 0;
if(int.TryParse(bufer[1], out ss2)){
    ss2.Value = ss2;
}
```

en este caso solo asignaria si pudo convertir

Answer (score 1):

sabes que desde `ss1.Value` hasta `ss8.Value` siempre se van ha ejecutar.

A cada uno de los `if` debes de colocarles las llaves de apertura y cierre `{}`. Si solo necesitas ejecutar una instruccion si se cumple la condicion, entonce se puede utilizar sin las llaves, si lleva mas logica dentro del if, entonce debes de colocar las llaves.

La comparaciones dentro de los `if` siempre la haces que sea mayor a cero y no por cada tamaño que nesecitas.

```
string input = TxtDatosRecibidos.Text; 
char[] delimitador = { ',' };

string[] bufer = input.Split(delimitador);

if (bufer.Length > 0)
{
    textBox1.Text = bufer[0];
    ss1.Value =Int32.Parse(bufer[0]);
}

if (bufer.Length > 1)
{
    textBox2.Text = bufer[1];
    ss2.Value = Int32.Parse(bufer[1]);
}

if (bufer.Length > 2)
{
    textBox3.Text = bufer[2];
    ss3.Value = Int32.Parse(bufer[2]);
}

if (bufer.Length > 3)
{
    textBox4.Text = bufer[3];
    ss4.Value = Int32.Parse(bufer[3]);
}

if (bufer.Length > 4)
{
    textBox5.Text = bufer[4];
    ss5.Value = Int32.Parse(bufer[4]);
}

if (bufer.Length >= 5)
{
    textBox6.Text = bufer[5];
    ss6.Value = Int32.Parse(bufer[5]);
}

if (bufer.Length > 6)
{
    textBox7.Text = bufer[6];
    ss7.Value = Int32.Parse(bufer[6]);
}

if (bufer.Length > 7)
{
    textBox8.Text = bufer[7];
    ss8.Value = Int32.Parse(bufer[7]);
}
```

Comment: Pero menciona que el error es FormatException no que esta fuera de rango cuando acceder al array

Comment: Cierto, tienes razon. Aun asi pienso que los if en algun momento le van ha dar problemas con indices fueras de rango.